# iOS do the button's action before prepareSegue

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-storyboard

Basically, I have a button that when you press it, it runs its action methond (changes a field in my Data class) and segues into another view which displays the field.  After some debugging I realized that prepareSegue, and perhaps other related methods run before my button's action, and thus display the old field value instead of the new.  Is there anyway around this.  I was thinking maybe instead of segueing on the button press, I would create a segue to my first scene and segue to it at the end of my buttons action method, but am not sure how to set the destination of a segue made programmatically.  Or is there a better way to update the field before segueing?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't you `performSegue:` within the button selector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the segue is happening automatically you can do the work (field update) inside `prepareForSegue:`.  The segue you're given in that method can provide a reference to the new controller and the sender parameter should be your button.

Comment: the issue is, I actually have a table on the first page instead of a button, and need to know which cell was pressed. sorry for not saying that before I was trying to keep the question simple.

Comment: In that case, assuming the segue is attached to the cell, the cell should be available as the sender.  If you need to fetch some data that's related to the cell, the table view has a `indexPathForCell:` method to let you find offsets.

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work. I didn't realize that's what the sender was.