# NSUserDefaults returns before it has been set

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4.5

Im making an app that takes two strings and an int. I want these to be displayed on another view.

I have put them into an array and Im trying to store them in the NSUserDefaults. I have managed to get this data stored. The problem that im having is that when I change the data and save it again The function that gets the array is called before the one that sets it . So the application always displays the previous data.

I thought It would be easy to fix by changing when the functions are called.

but from the code it looks to me lie they are in the right order.

```
2012-09-26 13:55:02.764 BeerDivider[4377:907] array returnd = (
    2,
    "Person 1",
    "Person 2"
)
2012-09-26 13:55:02.773 BeerDivider[4377:907] array saved = (
    5,
    "Person 1",
    "Person 2"
)
```

I can see from logging the array that they are called in the wrong order.

Please can anyone see where im going wrong. This is my first objective-c/xcode post so not sure what code you want to see. I will put in all of it.

http://pastebin.com/BX5gqp17

Sorry if this is a lot of code.

Thanks for the help.

EDIT: update the code

EDIT2: I think what is happening is similar to this [iOS do the button's action before prepareSegue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11689985/ios-do-the-buttons-action-before-preparesegue)

Comment: How are the view controllers loaded? I don't see that in the code. If it's in a tab bar controller maybe the second is being loaded first? I don't see anything glaringly obvious that's wrong in the code. Try tracing the code paths with breakpoints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First Take a look on Apple documentation of [NSUserDefault](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
NSUserDefault always return the data which you saved in it

Dont forgot to write  `[defaults synchronize];`

```
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:yourArray forKey:@"YourKey"]
    [defaults synchronize];
```

According to your given code.

```
-(void)saveInfo:(NSArray *)myArray
    {
         NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:myArray forKey:@"array"];
    [defaults synchronize];
    NSLog (@"array saved = %@", [defaults objectForKey:@"array"]);
    }
```

and now check result

Comment: Thank you soooo much. I have spent hour trying to fix this!

Comment: it is still returning the pervious array

Comment: @Will Of course it is returning the original array :) in your pastebin code you are using NSLog on the original array, not the one in NSUserDefaults.

Comment: in ApplicationViewController.m   
-(void)saveInfo:(NSArray *)myArray

Comment: @rajneesh071 really? Its still giving me the incorrect array on my application

Comment: Take a look on @NSPostWhenIdle's comment..:)

Comment: Side note, you should look into different ways to pass information between view controllers, this is not what NSUserDefaults is for.

Comment: I changed the code but no working. The problem isnt that it is logging correctly it is logging find but appearing on the application wrong.

Comment: @Will There are several ways and they are all good under different circumstances. However, considering you just need a clean simple way to move a minimal amount of data you should create the array in your app delegate and read/write to it there.

Comment: @NSPostWhenIdle Do you know of any good tutorials that could help me. I can really find much about passing data around

Comment: I usually use a singleton. This would be done in its own class instead of the AppDelegate, which is generally preferred.  http://www.daveoncode.com/2011/12/19/fundamental-ios-design-patterns-sharedinstance-singleton-objective-c/

Comment: @Dcritelli Why is so hard to move something so simple!

Comment: @Dcritelli could you possible should me an example in past bin of something?

Comment: Yes, but honestly, even though it's not the best method. Saving to the user defaults should work. There's something in the code path that you're missing. Take a look at my comment on the original post and go over how the application is executing carefully.

Comment: @Dcritelli Thank you very much for the example :). I have used it to store the array. but the problem still exists. I assume this means that the function are just firing in the wrong order. Where was your original comment that says how it is executing?

Comment: @Rajneesh071 The problem still exists even when I use the singleton pattern. I think its to do with when event happen?

Comment: @Rajneesh071 its in a pastebin link on my question. I think it is that my code in the ViewDidLoad runs before the code to set the array on the button press.

Comment: Here is a copy of the project https://www.dropbox.com/sh/dfkudw71caq3gh1/X5SOLI4bY6

Comment: I have go it working now! Finally. This is what the problem was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623060/how-to-perform-uibutton-action-before-loading-next-view

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
-(void)saveInfo:(NSArray *)myArray
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:myArray forKey:@"array"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; //u forgot this
    NSLog (@"array saved = %@", myArray);
}
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much. I have spent hour trying to fix this!