# How to access data of NSMutableDictionary from view controller to previous view controller in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I am trying to do is data in NSMutableDictionary showing in UITableview but, I want to show in tableview when user press back button and come to previous view controller. I have one view controller on which tableview but whenever user push that view and go to next view there are some textfield, that textfield text value I am saving in one dictionary, Now I want to access that dictionary in previous view controller to show data in tableview.

I am already set the setter and getter for that dictionary. Then also I am getting null dictionary.
Please help me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: use model class that store your data and used in both class.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12602580/nsuserdefaults-returns-before-it-has-been-set/12602643#12602643

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509999/i-have-nsstring-value-in-addviewcontroller-and-i-want-to-display-this-value-in-u/13619879#13619879

Answer (score 0):

There are two options for solving your problem.

1. You can use a data container class which will hold all your shared data between view controllers. http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/54859-sharing-data-between-view-controllers-other-objects.html
2. By using delegates: [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)